# How do you sort MS project subtasks by date

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-server-2010

I created a MS project WBS with a number of Main tasks and a lists of sub tasks listed under each main task, these sub task may be carried out by a different user than who looks over th main task, hence may have different start and end dates.

I want to sort the WBS according to user and finish date, but the sorting is only applied to main tasks, sub tasks under aren't sorted.

Could someone tell me if there's a way to do this? thanks

i.e : I tried sorting by duration, this does sort subtasks but it doesnt display main tasks these subtasks are listed under. that becomes it harder to identify which is which since several subtask may have the same wording ex: Review

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say users I guess you mean resources assigned to tasks... For this you also need to use the Group by function. Please see http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/project-help/sort-tasks-resources-or-dates-HA102809651.aspx for more details.